# Order Table By Renamed Column

Tags: mysql

[image: DataBase Table]

Above is an example of my database table...

I want to achieve a result where userFrom = '1' OR userTo = '1'... Then I want to ORDER the results by `date`, I don't have a column with the name `date`, so I want `userFromDate` and `userToDate` to act as the column `date`. But `userFromDate` will only act as `date` WHERE userFrom = '1' AND `userToDate` will only act as `date` WHERE userTo = '1'.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT userFromDate AS date FROM startmessage WHERE userFrom = '1' UNION SELECT userToDate AS date FROM startmessage WHERE userTo = '1') t WHERE t.type = 'normal' ORDER BY t.date DESC LIMIT 0, 14
```

But I get this error

[image: Query Error]

Please anyone with a better solution?

Comment: It is hard to assess what you are trying to accomplish from just a non-working query. Please provide sample data and desired results, both as tabular text (no images).

Comment: It would be preferable if you were to format your query so it's easy to read, instead of a long line. As GMB mentioned, it would also be preferable if you were to include the errors in text. Surely you can appreciate that for anyone to give you a proper answer, they need to create this table, and create the data in it.. then run your query and fix it. Your image instead of text of the data is not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not selecting type in your subquery:

`(SELECT userFromDate AS date FROM startmessage WHERE userFrom = '1' UNION SELECT userToDate AS date FROM startmessage WHERE userTo = '1')`

This subquery is only selecting `userFromDate`, not `type`, so you're trying to select `type` on a result set which doesn't contain that column.

Just add the column, and it should work:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT type, userFromDate AS date FROM startmessage WHERE userFrom = '1' UNION SELECT type, userToDate AS date FROM startmessage WHERE userTo = '1') as t WHERE t.type = 'normal' ORDER BY t.date DESC LIMIT 0, 14`

Comment: You're still getting `#1054 - Unknown column 't.type' in 'where clause'`?

Comment: No... I still get `7 errors were found during analysis.`

Comment: Lol, so are they the same 7 errors, or a different 7 errors?

Comment: Ah, there's something else that was wrong with your code. You need (select ...) **as** table_name. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I can't help if you don't give me the specific error. Error counts are essentially useless if we don't know what they are.

Comment: Okay... Ur edited answer worked for me, thanks man I appreciate